# Aggregating all values from each child property that belongs to a parent key on JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, web-frontend

This is my current data structure

```
{
    key1: [
        {
            a: 123,
            b: 100,
            c: 300,
            start_date: “05-01-2021”
        },
        {
            a: 123,
            b: 100,
            c: 300,
            start_date: “06-01-2021”
        },
        {
            a: 123,
            b: 100,
            c: 300,
            start_date: “07-01-2021”
        }
    ],
    key2: [
        {
            a: 123,
            b: 100,
            start_date: “05-01-2021”
        },
        {
            a: 123,
            b: 100,
            start_date: “06-01-2021”
        },
        {
            a: 123,
            b: 100,
            start_date: “07-01-2021”
        }
    ]
}
```

Each object in the array has a key-value pair called `start_date`, which I am trying to match on.

Basically, I’m trying to each element in key1 that matches the start_time with each element in key2, and it can be for N number of key1  - keyN

I’ve tried some solutions with reduce, and running it through a loop, but I’m trying to find a elegant solution that doesn’t have me creating for loops.

The end result I want is:

```
{
    key1: [
        {
            a: 123,
            b: 100,
            c: 300,
            start_date: “05-01-2021”
        },
        {
            a: 123,
            b: 100,
            c: 300,
            start_date: “06-01-2021”
        },
        {
            a: 123,
            b: 100,
            c: 300,
            start_date: “07-01-2021”
        }
    ],
    key2: [
        {
            a: 123,
            b: 100,
            start_date: “05-01-2021”
        },
        {
            a: 123,
            b: 100,
            start_date: “06-01-2021”
        },
        {
            a: 123,
            b: 100,
            start_date: “07-01-2021”
        }
    ],
    key3: [
        {
            a: 246,
            b: 200,
            c: 300,
            start_date: “05-01-2021”
        },
        {
            a: 246,
            b: 200,
            c: 300,
            start_date: “06-01-2021”
        },
        {
            a: 246,
            b: 200,
            c: 300,
            start_date: “07-01-2021”
        }
    ]

}
```

All arrays will always be the same length.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) as well as [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) in order to aggregate all the values in the input object.

Then use [object destructuring and the spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create a new object which contains all previous objects as well as a new key with the aggregated values.

Here a working solution with comments explaining the steps.

```js
const input = {
  key1: [
    {
      a: 123,
      b: 100,
      c: 300,
      start_date: "05-01-2021",
    },
    {
      a: 123,
      b: 100,
      c: 300,
      start_date: "06-01-2021",
    },
    {
      a: 123,
      b: 100,
      c: 300,
      start_date: "07-01-2021",
    },
  ],
  key2: [
    {
      a: 123,
      b: 100,
      start_date: "05-01-2021",
    },
    {
      a: 123,
      b: 100,
      start_date: "06-01-2021",
    },
    {
      a: 123,
      b: 100,
      start_date: "07-01-2021",
    },
  ],
};

// we only need the values
const aggregated = Object.values(input)
  // flatten it so we get one array with all entries
  .flatMap(x => x)
  // now reduce using start_date as a key
  .reduce((agg, cur) => {
    if (agg[cur.start_date]) {
      // we already have a key for this date => aggregate
      const toBeUpdated = agg[cur.start_date];
      // ever entry may have props...
      // - we already know     => aggregate/ sum up
      // - we do not yet know  => set property = current value of that entry
      Object.keys(cur).forEach(k => k !== "start_date" && toBeUpdated[k] ? toBeUpdated[k] += cur[k]: toBeUpdated[k] = cur[k]);
    } else agg[cur.start_date] = { ...cur }; // this is a new date => just copy the props and valus from the current enty
    return agg;
  }, {});
  
// this is the aggregation done
console.log("Result of aggregation:")
console.log(JSON.stringify(aggregated, null, 4));

console.log("Desired output:")
// Now create a new output object which has a new key value set to the values of what we've aggregated before
const output = {...input, [`key${Object.keys(input).length + 1}`]: Object.values(aggregated)};
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```